# HttpStatus 207 response body suggestions

Tags: rest, http, http-status-codes

I was wondering how the response body should look like when the HttpStatus is **207 Multi-status**. I failed to find any examples online.

I was thinking something like a list that contains the failed status and the reason for it for each sub-request.

```
[
    {
        "status" : 404,
        "reason" : "Resource not found"
    },
    {
        "status" : 500,
        "reason" : "Something went wrong internally"
    }
]
```

Is this the right aproach ? Should I include something else ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Follow the specs: the [Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) Status Code Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml) will tell you that the reference for 207 Multi-Status is [RFC 4918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918.html#section-11.1), which internally links to a section on [Multi-Status Response](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918.html#section-13)

> The default Multi-Status response body is a text/xml or application/xml HTTP entity with a 'multistatus' root element.  Further elements contain 200, 300, 400, and 500 series status codes generated during the method invocation. 100 series status codes SHOULD NOT be recorded in a 'response' XML element.

To get a better sense for how it is used in practice, you should probably look into one of the [open source WebDAV](https://github.com/fstanis/awesome-webdav) projects (ex: [Apache mod_dav](https://github.com/omnigroup/Apache/blob/master/httpd/modules/dav/main/mod_dav.c)).